# Why do 100 rect contain 400 tris?

Tags: unity, c#, performance

I am making a game targeted towards mobile, so I am experimenting around to know how I can boost performance.

Now I have a rectangle with a road texture on it. This I made in Blender. And as expected it has 2 tris.

I made a c# script to add these rectangles together to make a long road. So if I make a road 100 unit long, I have 100 such rectangles, and I expect that their total tris count becomes 200.

[image]

Now while running the game, Stats panel shows 8.2k tris for entire scene. And when I disable this 100 unit long road, Stats shows 7.8k tris. So why are there 400 tris for 100 rects?

For each rectangle object, I have already turned off the "cast shadows" property.

Link to blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BztX2HefTk_wb1VuSUlONXVxaE0/view?usp=sharing

Link to texture file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BztX2HefTk_wc3JvdTBJZmphRUU/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT (adding code for builder script)**

```
void createRoad() {
    Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(270, 0, 0);

    float z_size; // Value assigned in CreateWizard()
    Object road_item; // Assigned in CreateWizard()

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        GameObject roadPiece = (GameObject)Instantiate (road_item);
        roadPiece.transform.parent = ((GameObject)Selection.objects[0]).transform;
        roadPiece.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, i * z_size);

        roadPiece.transform.localEulerAngles = rotation;
        roadPiece.name = BASE_NAME + (i+1);

        //Turn Off cast-shadows
        roadPiece.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().shadowCastingMode = 
            UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like it is rendering twice, maybe once for a depth only pre-pass? That's a common technique to help overdraw problems.  It might also be rendering once per light, if you have it lit by two lights.

Comment: @AlanWolfe: I have a single light only.

Comment: What format is your blender data? I'd look carefully at the model to make sure it really is exactly 2 triangles in your object.

Comment: What's to the left of your road?  The white patch?  How did you make your skybox?  What about the grey patch on the far left, between the white section and the skybox (or is it just part of the skybox gradient)?

Comment: Is it set up to render both sides of the triangles? Ie is backface culling off? If so some engines implement that by drawing things twice. Once for the inside, once for the outside.

Comment: @davidvanbrink: Added links to blender and its texture file

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: The white patch is the terrain. I haven't modified skybox. Everything apart from terrain and road is default stuff, that I got with new scene.

Comment: @AlanWolfe: I don't know, can you elaborate on this in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at it from underneath, can you still see it or does it disappear?

Comment: @AlanWolfe: I rotated the road 180 degrees, and it disappeared.

Comment: Oh OK. Never mind to what I said then, it isn't a double sided polygon issue.

Comment: You said that you're connecting multiple road segments, so make sure you're not drawing triangles in between individual segments. So like if you have two segments |\| |\| make sure that you're not connecting them like this |\|/|\| or something and that they're actually individual rectangles simply lined up.

Comment: Without any code though it's pretty much anybody's guess... :P

Comment: @Superdoggy: Added code. And I am not drawing triangles. I am simply placing rectangle objects side by side.

Comment: @VinayakGarg - Yeah, that's what I'm getting at: how many polys are in your terrain?  And the skybox likely takes up a few too (although probably not that many).  To verify this is a road-related problem, what happens if you set `count` to 1?  Do you really need to get the parent and set the shadow casting off in the loop?  I would have expected that to remain unchanged....

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I disabled-enabled the terrain to see that it takes 3.1k tris. I created a new road with count 1, it didn't have any effect on tris count. I don't get shadow casting property toggle in parent, so I have to do it on individual child. BTW if I have shadow on for 100 unit long road, it takes up 0.2k extra tris.